# How to find all units in $ \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-2}] $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let be$$ \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-2}]= \{ a+ b \sqrt{-2}] |a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} $$

I want to find all units in  $ \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-2}] $

I found some similar questions..but I am still not sure how to work on that..

so take $ \phi(a+ b\sqrt{-2})= a^2 +2b^2 $

properties of the norm : $ |ab| = |a||b| $

so If there is an unit $ \alpha \in \mathbb{Z} [ \sqrt{-2}]$
than it must be $|\alpha \beta |=1= |\alpha| |\beta|$
so the only units would be $\alpha= -1 $ and $\alpha=1$?

I feel like this is not complete..would appreciate any help of you!!

Comment: You mean $a^2+2b^2=1$

Comment: Yup, $\pm1$ are the only units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.  Imaginary quadratic domains tend to be like that.